# Nav issues - fixed-top breaks navbar-right and covers logo

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using a bootstrap Nav for this page
http://careers.baffinland.com

I added the fixed-top class as I need a sticky top, but that then overrides navbar-right class and aligns the menu to the left.  It also covers up my logo which was aligned left.

In addition i would like to hamburger responsive menu to open to the left, when you open in responsive mode, the drop down is stuck to the right of the button (this wont be clear until menu is aligned right again) which forces the toggle to jump to the middle of the page

```
             <!-- <div class="site-nav col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-9">-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-nav-bar fixed-top " role="navigation" style="max-width: 1360px; margin: 0 auto;">


    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->

    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-controls="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="http://careers.baffinland.com/wp-content/themes/darkStarMediaTheme/images/logo.png" width="236"  alt="Baffinland logo" class="banner-logo " style="float: left; text-align:left; left: 0px;"  /></a>
        <div id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" class="collapse navbar-collapse"><ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"><li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children dropdown menu-item-16 nav-item"><a title="About Us" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" id="menu-item-dropdown-16">About Us</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="menu-item-dropdown-16" role="menu">
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-17 nav-item"><a title="Who We Are" href="https://www.baffinland.com/about-us/who-we-are/" class="dropdown-item">Who We Are</a></li>

</ul>
</li>
<li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children dropdown menu-item-20 nav-item"><a title="Operation" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" id="menu-item-dropdown-20">Operation</a></li>
</ul></div>   
</nav>
       <!--  </div> -->
```

Comment: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) You are required to post a [mcve] here, within your question and not a link to your site or any third party site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, navbar-right worked before I added the fixed-top class, you can disable fixed-top and try for yourself...

regardless, I did try your solution and it didn't work. I do appreciate the help though..

What I did do was this, I just added right margins to navbar-brand and pushed it over to where I wanted it

Answer (score 1):

Your logo is outside of your navbar and your "navbar-brand" is on "display-none".

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-nav-bar fixed-top" role="navigation" style="max-width: 1360px; margin: 0 auto;">


    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->

    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-controls="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <a href="http://careers.baffinland.com/" class="navbar-brand" title="Baffinland Iron Mines" rel="home"><img src="http://careers.baffinland.com/wp-content/themes/darkStarMediaTheme/images/logo.png" width="236" alt="Baffinland logo" class="banner-logo " style="float: left; text-align:left; left: 0px;"></a>
    <div id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children dropdown menu-item-16 nav-item">
                <a title="About Us" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" id="menu-item-dropdown-16">About Us</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="menu-item-dropdown-16" role="menu" style="display: none;">
                    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-17 nav-item">
                        <a title="Who We Are" href="https://www.baffinland.com/about-us/who-we-are/" class="dropdown-item">Who We Are</a>
                    </li>
                    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-18 nav-item">
                        <a title="Our Leadership" href="https://www.baffinland.com/about-us/our-leadership/" class="dropdown-item">Our Leadership</a>
                    </li>
                    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-19" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-19 nav-item">
                        <a title="FAQ" href="http://www.baffinland.com/about-us/faq/" class="dropdown-item">FAQ</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children dropdown menu-item-20 nav-item">
                <a title="Operation" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" id="menu-item-dropdown-20">Operation</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="menu-item-dropdown-20" role="menu" style="display: none;">
                    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-21 nav-item">
                        <a title="Mary River Mine" href="http://www.baffinland.com/operation/mary-river-mine/" class="dropdown-item">Mary River Mine</a>
                    </li>
                    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-22 nav-item">
                        <a title="Shipping &amp; Monitoring" href="http://www.baffinland.com/operation/shipping-and-monitoring/" class="dropdown-item">Shipping &amp; Monitoring</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-23" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children dropdown menu-item-23 nav-item">
                <a title="Sustainability" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" id="menu-item-dropdown-23">Sustainability</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="menu-item-dropdown-23" role="menu">
                    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-24 nav-item">
                        <a title="Overview" href="http://www.baffinland.com/sustainability/overview/" class="dropdown-item">Overview</a>
                    </li>
                    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-25 nav-item">
                        <a title="Health &amp; Safety" href="http://www.baffinland.com/sustainability/health-and-safety/" class="dropdown-item">Health &amp; Safety</a>
                    </li>
                    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-26" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-26 nav-item">
                        <a title="Environment" href="http://www.baffinland.com/sustainability/environment/" class="dropdown-item">Environment</a>
                    </li>
                    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-27 nav-item">
                        <a title="Communities" href="http://www.baffinland.com/sustainability/communities/" class="dropdown-item">Communities</a>
                    </li>
                    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-28 nav-item">
                        <a title="Learning &amp; Development" href="http://www.baffinland.com/sustainability/learning-and-development/" class="dropdown-item">Learning &amp; Development</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-11 current_page_item active menu-item-29 nav-item">
                <a title="Careers" href="http://careers.baffinland.com/" class="nav-link">Careers</a></li>
            <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children dropdown menu-item-30 nav-item">
                <a title="Media Centre" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" id="menu-item-dropdown-30">Media Centre</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="menu-item-dropdown-30" role="menu" style="display: none;">
                    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-31" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-31 nav-item">
                        <a title="News Releases" href="http://www.baffinland.com/media-centre/news-releases/" class="dropdown-item">News Releases</a>
                    </li>
                    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-32" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-32 nav-item">
                        <a title="Media Gallery" href="http://www.baffinland.com/media-centre/media-gallery/" class="dropdown-item">Media Gallery</a>
                    </li>
                    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-33" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-33 nav-item">
                        <a title="Document Portal" href="http://www.baffinland.com/media-centre/document-portal/" class="dropdown-item">Document Portal</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-34" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children dropdown menu-item-34 nav-item">
                <a title="Contact Us" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" id="menu-item-dropdown-34">Contact Us</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="menu-item-dropdown-34" role="menu" style="display: none;">
                    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-35" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-35 nav-item">
                        <a title="Contact Information" href="http://www.baffinland.com/contact-us/contact-information/" class="dropdown-item">Contact Information</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I put your logo into the "nav" tag, maybe this helps you more to figure out. I recommend to copy one of these templates, so your html structure will work. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/navbar/

Comment: Thank you, that helped with the logo, the main issue persists though, the menu is still left aligned and ignoring navbar-right

Comment: This is because the ".navbar-right" class dosen't exist.
You can define your own css for "navbar-right" like: "justify-content: flex-end;". This will align all menu items right.

Comment: It does exists, if I remove  fixed-top, everything right aligns, I've used it on countless websites with this theme

Comment: it is built into bootstrap, scroll 1/4 way down this page https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp

Comment: Your link links to a bootstrap 3 tutorial, but my analyzer says that you are using bootstrap 4. Anyway, just try to use "justify-content:flex-end" on your navbar-right class.